# How clean faster a content view with Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I clean a div of content view with:

```
$(".box2").empty();
```

After, It renders the next view (without remove the model). If last view had much content, when load the next view, residues of last view are shown for a time yet.
How can solve this problem?

Code:

```
    var Contents = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "body", 
        events: {
            "click .addAll": "addContentAll", "click .addFront": "addContentChart"    
        },
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this); 
            this.model = new ContentCollection();
            this.model.on("add", this.contentAdded);
        },          
        addContentAll: function(event) {
                    this.model.add({name: "all"});  
                    //some content or plugin
        },  
        addContentChart: function(event) {
                    this.model.add({name: "chart"});
                    //charts content
        },         
        contentAdded: function(content) {
            if (content.view == null) {
                var template_name;              
                switch(content.get("name")){        
                    case 'all': template_name = 'all'; break; 
                    case 'chart': template_name = 'chart'; break;  
                }                                       
                content.view = new ContentView({model: content,template: $.trim($("[data-template-name='"+ template_name +"'] div").html() || "Template not found!")});
                $(".box2").empty(); 
                this.$el.find(".content").find("div.box2").append(content.view.render().el);                                                 
            }       
        }   
   });
var ContentView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: "div",
            template: null,
            initialize: function() {
                _.bindAll(this);
                this.template = this.options.template; 
            },
            render: function() {        
                this.$el.html(Mustache.render(this.template, this.model.toJSON())); 
                return this; 
            }
 });     
 var view = new Contents();
```

After `empty()` the content is rendered. Is there any way to check when the `empty()`function is made? I think that it returns void. It would be a good way to use a loading indicator and then render the view.

Solved:
The conflict was in another plugin of content.

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/WZeS7/1/

Comment: Think about a loading indicator like a spinner.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle loading indicator will freeze during rendering. I have updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/WZeS7/4/

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk. What do you mean with "can't reproduce"?

Comment: your fiddle works like it should. It empties the div and the renders the view.

Comment: @vicenrele, I think you should be more specific describing your problem and **required** results. That will help to give you good answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct answer to your question of clearing a div, but have you tested whether you could get faster performance by creating another in the same spot (that is, <div id="imHidden"></div><div id="imVisible"></div>), filling it while it's still hidden, and then switch the hidden/shown state on each of the two divs?

If this is something you have to do often within the UI, you might even have two divs you switch back and forth between. One visible, one not, and any operations to fill or empty a div take place only on whichever one is currently hidden.

Comment: Great idea! I will try it. I think that the div is made empty very slow because the content of charts is heavy